# VBA troubleshoot, copy one cell in one workbook to another cell in another workbook based on two criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, one which is my main overview and another which is a trimmed down copy of my main workbook, which a colleague uses to write notes based on his contacts with the people listed in our shared lists.

I want to copy my colleagues notes into an appropriate column, by checking to see if the name and ID of the people are the same.  So, I want to make sure the notes for Mike Smith, #12 get copied to his row and not the row for Mike Smith #77.

My thought was to do two loops, one that goes through each row of the main sheet and then for that particular main sheet row, loops through all the note sheet rows, looking for matches of ID and names, and when it finds a match for both, copies the notes in that row in the note sheet to  the main sheet in the appropriate column.

Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim jbBook As Workbook

Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set jbBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\noteWorkbook.xslx")

For i = 2 To 200
    For x = 2 To 200
        If Cells(i, 5) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 5) Then If Cells(i, 16) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 16) Then Cells(i, 52) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 34)

    Next x
Next i

jbBook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? If so, where?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, no error, just no update on the main book.  It obviously opens the note book, pauses a second, then closes the note book, but nothing is updated on the main book.  I first tried this without the if statements and without the nested loop, and it worked fine, just copying one column to another, just confused if there are some vague aspect of conditionals that VBA has that I'm not appreciating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with this:

```
If Cells(i, 5) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 5) Then
```

Try changing it to

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Cells(i, 5) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 5) Then
```

I believe that the unreferenced `Cells()` is what's giving the error. You would, of course, have to change all of them.

You may also consider breaking the If/Thens onto separate lines, just for readability.

Comment: Did you mean change Cells to: 

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = jbBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 5) Then

Because wouldn't using jbBook.worksheets(1)... just reference the same sheet twice?

Comment: Yes, if that's the destination. My apologies, I've fixed it.

Comment: Well it looks like that did get stuff to copy over, I just have to go through and see if it is actually doing the conditional check right.  Thanks for the help, I assume there is some way to give you props for the help on this?

Comment: The check for the correct answer is good. An up-vote is an added bonus. Glad I could help. Always easier to solve someone else's problem than your own...